# Pascal Script Fast Reports

Tags: delphi, pascal, fastreport

EDIT:

Im having to edit some old Pascal Script in Fast Reports and are having a tough time returning only distinct records. Any help would be appreciated.

So Basically, I am calling a stored proc to return data in a table. In one of these columns there sometimes are a 1 letter code (A,B,C) that defines which rtf file to go fetch for the report.

Currently It does go fetch all of the rtf files for the respective codes, but sometimes the code is repeated (A,A) and in that case I need it to return only the DISTINCT rtf files. So If A was pulled allready, Dont Pull again and carry on looking for other codes in that Column

My Code:
NOTE: In Memo93 I am just inserting (table."Class")

```
    procedure GroupHeader17OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent );
var
       CarGroup: String     ;
       CarGroupLoop: String;  
begin  
                       CarGroup := Memo93.Value;
                       if not(CarGroup = CarGroupLoop) then
                       begin
                               try
                                       GroupHeader17.Visible := TRUE;
                                       rich23.richedit.lines.LoadFromFile('example\'+ trim(Get('@QteLanguage'))+ '\'+ trim(Get('@QteLanguage'))+'_Group_'+ trim(<Table."class">)+ '.rtf');

                               except
                                       GroupHeader17.Visible := FALSE;

                               end;
                       end
                       else
                       begin
                               GroupHeader17.Visible := False;
                       end;

                       CarGroupLoop := <table."Class">;

end;
```

This Seem to have done the job and only bring back distinct rtf files.

```
procedure GroupHeader17OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent );
var
       CarGroup: String     ;
       CarGroupLoop: String;
begin
                       CarGroup := Memo93.Value;
                       CarGroupLoop :=  <table."Class">;
                       if not(CarGroup = CarGroupLoop) then
                       begin
                               try
                                       GroupHeader17.Visible := TRUE;
                                       rich23.richedit.lines.LoadFromFile('example\'+ trim(Get('@QteLanguage'))+ '\'+ trim(Get('@QteLanguage'))+'_Group_'+ trim( <table."Class">)+ '.rtf');

                               except
                                       GroupHeader17.Visible := FALSE;

                               end;
                       end
                       else
                       begin
                               GroupHeader17.Visible := False;
                       end;



end;
```

Comment: It sounds you want to cache already loaded files (where the file name is composed by the char read from a dataset) to prevent loading the same file (for the same char). But I don't get what you mean by the loop you mention. Could you elaborate your question, please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that you have neglected to ask a question, so attaining an answer will prove challenging. Please [edit] your question to clarify precisely what you need an answer to. You might start with pointing out what loop you're having trouble with, given that there is no loop shown right now.

Comment: I basically need to know how I can get a distinct list of codes from a column in a data table by using a loop. The pasted code still shows duplicates. So what I meant was. How would I go about to loop through the rows of a table.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `CarGroup :=  <table."Class">;` and move `CarGroupLoop :=  <table."Class">;` at the end of GroupHeader17OnBeforePrint event

```
    procedure GroupHeader17OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent );
var
       CarGroup: String     ;
       CarGroupLoop: String;  
begin  
                       CarGroup :=  <table."Class">;
                       if not(CarGroup = CarGroupLoop) then
                       begin
                               try
                                       GroupHeader17.Visible := TRUE;
                                       rich23.richedit.lines.LoadFromFile('example\'+ trim(Get('@QteLanguage'))+ '\'+ trim(Get('@QteLanguage'))+'_Group_'+ trim(<Table."class">)+ '.rtf');

                               except
                                       GroupHeader17.Visible := FALSE;

                               end;
                       end
                       else
                       begin
                               GroupHeader17.Visible := False;
                       end;

                       CarGroupLoop := <table."Class">;

end;
```

Comment: Hi. That is How I had it first. See first Code bracket on my post

Comment: Use `CarGroup :=  <table."Class">;` instead of `CarGroup := Memo93.Value;`

Comment: Thanks for the try. But its not that

Comment: Create small demo project with problem and send it to support@fast-report.com

Comment: I sent the demo to support

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var CarGroup: String;      //global variable

procedure GroupHeader17OnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
var CarGroupLoop: String ;
begin
     CarGroupLoop := trim(<rpt_1_RHINO_Costing_Curr_Totals."SupplierClassCodeTransport">);
     if not(CarGroup = CarGroupLoop) then
       begin
         try
            //rich23.richedit.lines.LoadFromFile('D:\Data\Shares\GlobeTrackNew\QuoteInfo\Suppliers\Bidvest\'+ trim(Get('@QteLanguage'))+ '\'+ trim(Get('@QteLanguage'))+'_Group_'+ trim(<rpt_1_RHINO_Costing_Curr_Totals."SupplierClassCodeTransport">)+ '.rtf');
            GroupHeader17.Visible := TRUE;
            //rich23.richedit.lines.LoadFromFile('D:\Data\Shares\GlobeTrackNew\QuoteInfo\Suppliers\Bidvest\GER\GER_Group_I.rtf');
         except
            GroupHeader17.Visible := FALSE;
         end;
       end
     else
       GroupHeader17.Visible := FALSE;
     CarGroup := trim(<rpt_1_RHINO_Costing_Curr_Totals."SupplierClassCodeTransport">);
end;

procedure SubCarHireOnBeforePrint(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  CarGroup := '';  
end;
```